# cannot install pipelight

Tags: software-installation, pipelight, netflix-desktop

I am running ubuntu 14.04 and keep running into trouble trying to install pipelight so I can watch Netflix. what is going wrong? here is the code I am using

```
matt@matt-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpwygd9m81/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpwygd9m81/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 25396B8E from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpwygd9m81/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 25396B8E: public key "Launchpad PPA for Pipelight Dev Team" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
matt@matt-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
matt@matt-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pipelight-multi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like apt is already running  that's what this means "Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock"

The reason it is unable to get the package is because update failed because it could not get the lock

I would suggest rebooting the computer so that apt fill clear itself up and then run this script that I use to setup my computer with netflix

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
sudo apt-get install -y netflix-desktop
```

if you still cannot get a lock then maybe remove the lock file though this is very questionable

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

## not done still editing

Comment: after restarting and runing the script i can get up to the install stage than get this text box for the end user licence and no way to click ok or agree to it

Comment: press Tab key to highlight the "OK" you see on the screen.  then press the enter key to accept the license.